# How do I transfer a .cpp and .h file from my local Mac laptop to my ssh linprog account for my uni's compiling system?

Tags: mac, ssh, unix

This is the command I am inputting into terminal:

```
scp /OOP_HW_M/House.cpp username@linprog:/OOP_HW
```

to transfer my source code file from my laptop to my linprog account
on my university's compiling system.

Output:

```
/OOP_HW_M/House.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

So then I tried to make a new file and to transfer that,
but that's also not working.

Comment: Normally you can use scp with the same credentials as ssh to.move files. Alternatively, see if you xan find an sftp which provides ftp type semantics over ssh if its not been disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're able to connect via ssh, one method of copying your file(s) over is to use the `scp` (secure copy) command.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy:

> Secure Copy Protocol. The SCP is a network protocol, based on the BSD
>   RCP protocol, which supports file transfers between hosts on a
>   network. SCP uses Secure Shell (SSH) for data transfer and uses the
>   same mechanisms for authentication, thereby ensuring the authenticity
>   and confidentiality of the data in transit.

In your case you'll want to run this command from your local computer:

```
scp ~/OOP_HW_M/House.cpp username@linprog:~/OOP_HW/
```